# How can I change StiWebViewer language and culture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, components, report, stimulsoft

I have a StiWebReport from StimulSoft components. I'd like to change the language to Persian (Farsi). The things with a line around them in the photo below, I'd like them to be in Persian.[image]

How do I do it? Or is there any feature which may be related? I already saw something like this somewhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set `GlobalizationFile` property of your `StiWebViewer`. In this property you can specify the path to a localization file and the report engine will do the rest for you.

Otherwise the report engine automatically  uses localization which is specified for current culture.

And you can find the Localization files in the following folder:

```
Program Files\Stimulsoft\Stimulsoft Reports.Net xx\.Net xx\Bin\Localization
```